# Why is applicationDidFinishLaunching not being called?

Tags: swift3, nsapplication

Today Apple came with a new Swift (again). After endless syntax changes I managed to compile (I needed to get rid of xcstate as well as it kept throwing nonsense error messages). But now my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is no longer being called.

Comment: The signature has changed slightly.

Comment: @vadian I found that out, but I guess that others will have that trouble too.

Comment: Actually the migrator is supposed to change the signatures accordingly.

Comment: @vadian Well, in my case it didn't. Plus a couple of other nasty things. <suppress-rant></suppress-rant>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you need to change it to

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
```

Probably I'm the only one using that method :-/